# USB and CD data cannot be read or mounted in 12.10

Tags: usb, mount, 12.10, ntfs, brasero

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10. I wrote a data disk using Brasero Disk Burner, but the system cannot read the CD.

I tried to write the same data into my HP v220w pen drive but now there is an error in that too. It shows the following:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb at /media/aravind4j/Aravind4j: 
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb" "/media/aravind4j/Aravind4j"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

I used a NTFS file system for the pen drive as you can recognize from the above statement.

I would like to recover the files so please help me recover the files without formatting the drive.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your NTFS file system is corrupt. Actions like pulling out the drive while write is happening, power failure and etc., can corrupt your drive. You could run `chdsk /f` on Windows as the error message suggests. Or you could use the suite of tools provided by the `ntfsprogs` package to fix the corruption. You could follow the instructions available at http://wmarkito.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/how-to-fix-mftmirr-does-not-match-mft-record-0/